# Determine what resource was not found from "Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm running `kubectl create -f notRelevantToThisQuestion.yml`

The response I get is:

> Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested
>   resource

Is there any way to determine which resource was requested that was not found?

`kubectl get ns` returns

> NAME          STATUS    AGE
>  default       Active    243d
>   kube-public   Active    243d
>  kube-system   Active    243d

This is not a cron job.
Client version 1.9
Server version 1.6

This is very similar to https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2956/how-do-i-get-kubernetes-to-work-when-i-get-an-error-the-server-could-not-find-t?rq=1 but my k8s cluster has been deployed correctly (everything's been working for almost a year, I'm adding a new pod now).

Answer (score 16):

To solve this, downgrade the client or upgrade the server. In my case I've upgraded server (new minikube) but forget to upgrade client (kubectl) and end up with those versions.

```
$ kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.9.0
Server Version: v1.14.1
```

When I'd upgraded client version (in this case to 1.14.2) then everything started to work again.

Instructions how to install (in your case upgrade) client are here https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl

Comment: The interesting case here is that `minikube version` shows 1.22.0 for me, but `minikube kubectl -- version` shows 1.21.2

Answer (score 0):

The cause of problem in versions:

From [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/release/versioning.md#supported-releases-and-component-skew)

> a client should be skewed no more than one minor version from the
>   master, but may lead the master by up to one minor version. For
>   example, a v1.3 master should work with v1.1, v1.2, and v1.3 nodes,
>   and should work with v1.2, v1.3, and v1.4 clients.

Comment: So how to fix it ?@Nick

Comment: @Karthikeyan Downgrade the client or upgrade the server

Answer (score 0):

From http://words.yuvi.in/post/kubectl-rbac/

Running `kubectl create -f notRelevantToThisQuestion.yml -v=8` will print all the HTTP traffic (requests and responses!) in an easy to read way. In this way, one can identify which resource is not available from the http responses.

Answer (score 0):

apply these and then try

mkdir -p $HOME/.kube

sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config

sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

Answer (score 0):

This solution is particularly for mac users.

Step 1:- Update kubernetes

```
brew upgrade kubernetes-cli
```

Step 2:- Overwrite it

```
brew link --overwrite kubernetes-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Openshift**, I was using old oc CLI version, after **updating to latest oc CLI** solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question when creating resource from Dashboard.

The resource was namespaced and I had no namespace selected. Selecting namespace fixed `the server could not find the requested resource` error.

[image: k8s dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't enable kubernetes from docker desktop.

I enabled it which worked.