# Server could not find the requested resource

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes

How to fix this? I am trying to get the version of kubectl but says server not found. I have already installed kubernetes in my PC.

[image]

Comment: how did you install kubernetes cluster? mostly, your `kubeconfig` is not set correctly.

Comment: please also check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180147/determine-what-resource-was-not-found-from-error-from-server-notfound-the-se if it helps

Comment: `kubectl` usually writes out text diagnostics, not an image.  Can you replace that image with the exact text of the error message?  Can you provide a [mcve] with details of how you set up your local Kubernetes configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the KUBECONFIG which indicates the list of address and certs of k8s api servers, contexts and users.

Once you configure it correctly, kubectl can reach to the server.

The default path of kubeconfig is ~/.kube/config.
Also you can specify it using environment variable `KUBECONFIG` and `--kubeconfig` flag with `kubectl` cli.
ex:

```
export KUBECONFIG=your_kubeconfig_file_path
kubectl config get-contexts
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using minikube - just start minikube that will sort this problem

'minikube start --memory=4096'