# Kubernetes Dashboard error when running minikube start guide

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to learn how to use Kubernetes and tried following the guide [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) to create a local Kubernetes cluster with Docker driver.

However, I'm stuck at step 3: Interact with your cluster. I tried to run `minikube dashboard` and I keep getting this error:

```
Unknown error (404)
the server could not find the requested resource (get ingresses.extensions)
```

My Kubernetes version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.2", GitCommit:"092fbfbf53427de67cac1e9fa54aaa09a28371d7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-16T12:59:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.1", GitCommit:"632ed300f2c34f6d6d15ca4cef3d3c7073412212", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-19T15:39:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Can someone point out where the problem lies please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed the minikube according to the same guide, both locally and with the help of cloud providor and ... it works for me :)
If you are just learning and starting your adventure with Kubernetes, try to install everything from scratch.

The error you are getting is related to different versions of Client and Server. When I have installed according to the same guide, following the instructions, my versions look like this:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.1", GitCommit:"632ed300f2c34f6d6d15ca4cef3d3c7073412212", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-19T15:45:37Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.1", GitCommit:"632ed300f2c34f6d6d15ca4cef3d3c7073412212", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-19T15:39:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

You have different versions. Client `v1.21.2` and Server `v1.22.1`. Additionally your `Platforms` are also not the same. If you want to solve this you need to upgrade your client version or downgrade the server version. For more see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180147/determine-what-resource-was-not-found-from-error-from-server-notfound-the-se).

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Mikołaj Głodziak, do you know how I can keep the `Platforms` consistent in the up/downgrade?

Comment: [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/) is the guide how to install (update) kubectl client version. It should help you. Look also [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/). You need to upgrade (or remove old version and install new one) kubectl client version for linux/amd64 architecture. Please upvote / accept the answer if it is helpul.